# How can I get plain text markup formatted with pdftotext?

Tags: pdftotext

I am using `pdftotext` for extract plain content from PDF files.

But the result has no format (ex: paragraphs, lists, etc). How can extract plain text from PDFs using `pdftotext` and get the result formatted in markup?

Actually im trying this:

```
pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8
```

are any other way to do this?

Comment: PDF files do not contain "paragraphs, lists, etc." *unless* it has specifically been tagged with the appropriate markup. If a PDF is not tagged, *every* utility (up to and including Adobe's own Acrobat Reader, the touchstone for PDF handling software) can only guess what a "paragraph" or "list" is.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible with `pdftotext`.

The result which is given returned `pdftotext -layout` is about the best you can get.

**[Markdown](http://commonmark.org/)** (or otherwise formatted) output of the text is currently not possible.

However there may be some developments in other areas (like `pdf.js`) which may achieve a similar thing in the future...

This "formatting" however will only reflect somehow the *visual appearance* of the PDF pages, and not match any *structural* document information (telling what is a 'headline', what is a 'list', what is a 'paragraph').

What @jongware wrote in his comment is fully correct:

> PDF files do not contain "paragraphs, lists, etc." unless it has specifically been *tagged* with the appropriate markup. If a PDF is not tagged, every utility (up to and including Adobe's own Acrobat Reader, the touchstone for PDF handling software) can only *guess* what a "paragraph" or "list" is.